# pyspark dataframe with regexp_replace function

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

i have a dataframe df=

```
name  state
null   CA
Julia  null
Robert null
null   NJ
```

where both `name` and `state` columns are string columns

I want to replace string `'null'` from `name` column into `None`.

When I tried using the `replace` function as below, it is converting all values from `name` column to `None`. It is not the result I expect, I want only `'null'` values to be converted to `None`.

```
df = df.withColumn('name', regexp_replace('name', 'null', None))
```

I am getting output as below, I guess it is not able to recognize `'null'`.

```
name  state
null   CA
null   null
null   null
null   NJ
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: how to do that Ronak

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
df.withColumn("name", F.when((F.col('name') == "null"), None)).show()
```

Output with filter on String `"null"` (as `None`'s string representation is also `null`, can be misleading by just the output)

```
df.filter(F.col('name').eqNullSafe("null")).show()
df.withColumn("name", F.when((F.col('name') == "null"), None)).filter(F.col('name').eqNullSafe("null")).show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: i tried this but it aint convertinf string null to None Ronak

Comment: @karthik with show() the representation will still be the same but the underlying value will change i.e. instead of string "null" it'll be None

Comment: @karthik Added two outputs for clarity on this